# romeo & juliet probability problem

Tags: probability

the first time that romeo confesses to juliet she responses positively with probability 50%. If she responses negatively he confesses again but with positive response probability 20%. If she responses negatively again he tries one last time with success rate 10%. what is the probability of them hooking up if he is willing to try 3 times?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: you may find it useful to know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. This does not seem a research question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Romeo gets a yes on first try with probability $0.5$. If he reaches the second stage (probability $0.5$), he gets a yes with probability $0.2$, so that's another $.5 \times .2 = 0.1$ If he reaches the third stage (probability $0.5 \cdot 0.8 = 0.4$), he gets a yes with probability $0.1$, so that's another $.4 \times .1 = 0.04$. Add these up to get $0.5+0.1+0.04 = 0.64$.